# why am I getting uri_redirect_mismatch error for a uri provided to me by the credentials.json file give to me by google api console?

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am getting a uri_redirect mismatch for a google api integration I want. The redirect uri I am given is by the quickstart.py i added to my python project using the manual given on https://developers.google.com/.

When I try to add the uri in oauth authorization console it gives me the following message (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSLZ5.png) .

[image]

By some research I found out that my redirect is missing 'www' is there any way I can add it to my redirect uri using the quickstart .py program? or is there any other way to enable google api on my pycharm environment? (I am a complete beginner to python so I would love any help)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are running the sample code then you are making an installed app which means you should not see a redirect uri error.   If you are then you created web application credentials on google cloud console installed of installed app credentials as directed by the tutorial.  Go create the correct credentials.

[How to create installed app credetials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwqJcyLQSSQ)